# Move working Joomla 2.5 site from subdomain to root now 500 errors at logout

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I created a Working Joomla 2.5 website in a sub domain.  When I moved the site to the root and out of the sub domain folder I get the following error when I log out. Fatal error: Call to a member function init() on a non-object in /directory/templates/rt_clarion/error.php on line 20

The build works fine in the sub domain but not in the root.  I've tried the stock Joomla Templates and I still get an error at logout.  I tried disabling the Joomla SEF, nothing. Anyone have any ideas what might be?

The site was moved by using akeeba backup and restoring it in the root directory.

I'm using Joomla 2.5.4, K2 v2.5.7, Rockettheme Template Clarion v1.2.  Again the build works flawlessly in the subdomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step find out what is causing the server to throw [a 500 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) - check your servers log file. It may be a simple as a permissions problem, eg. most servers are configure to throw [a 500 error if the destination has permissions of 777](http://www.google.com/search?q=apache+500+error+permission+777).

After moving a Joomla! installation from a sub-domain you may need to update the Global Configuration - you can either do this through the Admin screens or by directly editing `configuration.php`. This often happens when people create the Joomla! site in a sub-directory and the move the site and delete the sub-directory.

The things you need to check are the paths to things like log & tmp directories, e.g.

```
public $log_path = '/host/public_html/asite/sub-directory/logs';
public $tmp_path = '/host/public_html/asite/sub-directory/tmp';
```

May need to be changed to:

```
public $log_path = '/host/public_html/asite/logs';
public $tmp_path = '/host/public_html/asite/tmp';
```

Comment: Thanks after looking into the server logs I found that jbplugins missing some files in the media directory.  I replaced those missing files and it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest renaming the template directory and reinstalling that template since that is where the error is occurring, unless you're comfortable exploring the configuration/options for re_clarion

Answer (score 0):

1) Switch to the default template: If you still have errors, the problem is coming from new installation. If not, it's your template (go step 2).

2) Backup your Clarion template folder on your HDD and uninstall it from your backend.

3) Install it again and check for errors. If everythings is OK, overwrite your Clarion folder with backuped data.